# How to "FTP jail" with apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ftp

I need to allow someone access to my website via FTP, but there are a number of directories that the person must not be allowed to view or modify. For example, something like this:

```
private_info_1
public_info_1
private_info_2
public_info_2
```

In this example, the FTP user would need to be allowed to do stuff in the public directories, but not the private ones.

How do I go about doing this with an Apache server? I have cPanel and SSH access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache does not provide ftp access, you should ask for configuration of your particular FTP server.